# Relationship between eigenvalues when the same change is applied to two different adjacency matrices of graphs with the same eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I'm attacking to solve the graph isomorphism problem using the adjacent matrices.

I would appreciate it if someone could show me whether following conjecture works or not. I expect this conjecture to work.

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ symmetric matrices. Let the diagonal components of  $A$ and $B$ are $0$, and the other components are $0$ or $1$. Assume that there is no permutation matrix $P$ such that $A=P^t B P$. Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix   $Diag(d_{11},...,d_{nn})$, where $d_{ll} > 0$, and the other diagonal entries are $0$. Let $d_{ll}$ be an integer. Let the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ be $\lambda_i$, $\mu_i$, and arrange them in the descending order. Assume that $\lambda_i=\mu_i$ for all $i$. Let the eigenvalues of $A+D$ and $B+D$ be $\lambda'_i$, $\mu'_i$ and arrange them in the descending order.
Assume that $\lambda'_j \neq \lambda_j$ for more than one $j$. Also, assume that $\mu'_k \neq \mu_k$ for more than one $k$.

**Conjecture.** Under these conditions, there exists $i$ such that $\lambda'_i\ne \mu'_i$.

**Question.** Does this conjecture hold?

If this conjecture is correct, it is thought that graph isomorphism problem might be solved in polynomial time.
Also, even if the conjecture stated here is correct, there is a possibility that the graph isomorphism problem cannot be solved in polynomial time due to other factors.

My attempt: $\lambda + d\lambda = (\textbf{v} + d\textbf{v})^t (A + D) (\textbf{v} + d\textbf{v}), \lambda = \textbf{v}^t A \textbf{v}$.

I tried to derive $d\lambda$ and $d\textbf{v}$ for $\lambda$ and $\textbf{v}$ from the above equations, but it turned out to be a complicated formula and I couldn't get a smart insight.

When $d\textbf{v} = \textbf{0}$, $d\lambda = \textbf{v}^t D \textbf{v}$.
And when $d\lambda = 0$, $(A + dA - \lambda I)d\textbf{v} = -dA\textbf{v}$.

Let $\textbf{v_A}$, $\textbf{v_B}$ be the eigenvectors for $A$, $B$.
When the conjecture is correct, $(D - d\lambda I)(\textbf{v_A} + d\textbf{v_A} - \textbf{v_B} - d\textbf{v_B}) + (A - \lambda I) d\textbf{v_A} - (B - \lambda I) d\textbf{v_B} \neq \textbf{0}$ holds.

This Conjecture holds when $d\textbf{v} = \textbf{0}$.
So, I hope that the above proposition is correct. However, I don't know whether this conjecture is sufficient in general or not. I would like to know whether the conjecture holds without any restrictions.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Whether following  assumption is collect or not?

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ symmetric matrices consisting of elements with values ​​greater than or equal to $0$. ... 
In this case, there exists an $i$ such that $\lambda'_i≠\mu'_i$.

Comment: You should restate the 3rd paragraph in the form of a question or a conjecture. In any case, your conjecture in the 3rd paragraph is false.

Comment: Could you please show me the counterexample. And, please tell me where I'm wrong.

Comment: I hope that this does not mean that the hypothesis is wrong because the graph isomorphism problem cannot be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: In English, a question is supposed to be a sentence ending with "?". Currently, your post contains no question marks. And you should not call a conjecture "an assumption."

Comment: Thank you for teaching me how to write in English.
Since English is not my native language, I apologize for using an expression that may have caused misunderstanding.
I changed assumption to conjecture. and I used question sentence.

Comment: Not a problem. I will write a proper answer with a counter-example to this conjecture later on. (I have nothing to say about the graph isomorphism problem.)

Comment: I corrected your English in the 3rd paragraph. I did not correct the rest since I have no idea what  you are doing there and it is irrelevant anyhow.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my English sentences.
Also, thank you for showing me a counterexample.
I continue to think about whether there is a counterexample also when I restrict $A$ and $B$ to be adjacency matrices of graphs.
I added restrictions to the 3rd paragraph.
I would appreciate it if you could check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I will disprove your conjecture in the case $n=2$. (A general suggestion: If you have a linear algebra conjecture, try to check it for $2\times 2$ matrices first.)

Consider the following family of symmetric $2\times 2$ matrices with nonnegative entries and zero determinant:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a& 1 \\
1 & a^{-1}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Its eigenvalues are $a+a^{-1}=Tr(A)$ and $0$. For $t > 1$ take the matrix
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}
t& 0\\
0 & t^{-1}\end{bmatrix}
$$
and let $B:= T A T^{-1}$,
$$
B= \begin{bmatrix}
a& t^{2}\\
t^{-2} & a^{-1}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Its eigenvalues, of course, are the same as that of $A$. Since $t>1$, there are no permutation matrices conjugating $A$ and $B$. Now, take $D=Diag(0,d)$, the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $0, d$, where $d\ne 0$ (the case $D=Diag(d,0)$ is similar). Then
$$
A'= A+D, B'=B+D.
$$
The new matrices $A', B'$ still satisfy $TA'T^{-1}=B'$.  Hence, $A', B'$ still have the same sets of eigenvalues. At the same time, neither $0$ nor $Tr(A)$ are eigenvalues of $A'$ (I leave you this computation to work out). Hence, none of the eigenvalues of $A$ is an eigenvalue of $A'$. (Same for $B, B'$, of course.) Hence, for every value of $a>0, t >1$ and $d\ne 0$, we get a counter-example to your conjecture.